# Numbers 3 or 4: how to copy a chart completely?

Tags: numbers, keynote, copy-paste, iwork

I have Numbers 4.3, 3.6 and 2.3 installed on different computers.

I want to copy charts from Numbers to Keynote but when I do that in 4.3 or 3.6 the title, legend etc are omitted (and yes, I have tried "plain" copy as well as "copy as pdf" - the result is the same). I can export my file to Numbers 09 and open it in 2.3 and achieve my goal but that feels like a very inefficient and stupid workaround.

I found [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/09/15/copying-charts-reliably-out-of-numbers/) that suggested I should group the chart with its title and then copy the grouped object but it does not work since I am unable to select both the title and chart simultaneously.

How do I copy everything that belongs to a chart in Numbers to Keynote?

(Mostly working with pie charts at the moment if that matters)

Comment: Have you copied also the data table from which the chart is made? A quick and dirty way is to take a screen shot.

Comment: Data table? Why would I (typically) want to copy that to Keynote?

Comment: Because, and correct me if I’m wrong, the chart derives it’s data including the labels and titles from the table. Alternatively, charts can easily be made straight in Keynote the same way as in Numbers. Depends on what exactly why you must copy from Numbers. Cheers

Comment: iWork 09 does not need the table when copying charts from Numbers to Keynote.